# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot invoke observe on a background thread

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to implement an online tutorial. The app is crashing when I open a particular fragment and the error message in the title is what the logcat is relaying to me. The code snippet causing the issue is pasted below:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(ConditionsViewModel::class.java)
    bindUI()
}

private fun bindUI() = GlobalScope.launch{
    val getConditions = viewModel.conditions.await()
    getConditions.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        if(it == null) return@Observer

        tvConditions.text = it.toString()
    })
}
```

So the bindUI() method is called in onCreate() and the line that is causing the exception is when the Observer is called. Much appreciated if someone could direct me to what is causing this.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your view model shouldn't be returning the `conditions` `LiveData` asynchronously. Instead you should be querying your endpoint asynchronously and then populating the `LiveData` once you have your result.

You also probably shouldn't be using `GlobalScope` unless you have to. Instead you can use the scope of the view model itself.

So something like this:

**View Model**

```
val conditions = MutableLiveData<>()

init {

    viewModelScope.launch {

        conditions.value = ...
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
conditions.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {

    ...
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. I kind of understand. Having some trouble however fleshing out your implementation - sorry Im a complete beginner at this.

So in the ViewModel i've tried to implement the following:

val conditions = MutableLiveData<CurrentConditionsSpecified>()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            conditions.value = conditionsRepository.getCurrentConditions()
        }
    }

I'm getting a Type Mismatch on conditionsRepository.getCurrentConditions(), it says

Required: CurrentConditionsSpecified?
Found: LiveData<CurrentConditionsSpecified>

Comment: What are you struggling with?

Comment: I'm getting a type mismatch when setting value = conditionsRepository.getCurrentConditions()

I'm assuming since it is MutableLiveData a null check should be placed somewhere but cant seem to figure out where

Comment: Is `getCurrentConditions()` a suspend function?

Comment: It is a suspend function yes

Comment: Generally it makes no sense for a suspend function to return anything observable. Is it a one-time request or are you listening for updates?

Comment: Its pulling data from an API for weather conditions. I suppose its a one time request as its just pulling in the JSON data as a one time snapshot of the current conditions.

Comment: Ok I solved it with my original code by using GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main), probably not the ideal solution at this point but thanks for your help all the same

Comment: Yes that's a one-time request, keep it a suspend function but actually return the data itself from it, not `LiveData`. Then like in my answer you can put `conditions.value = conditionsRepository.getCurrentCondition()`.